# Screenshot specific windows?

Tags: linux, bash, image

is there a way to screenshot specific window in bash so if its unfocused it will still screenshot it?

```
sleep 10
while true;
    do 
        scrot ~/Screenshots/"$(date +"%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S").png" 
        play ~/.custom-stuff/pew.mp3 vol 0.2 > /dev/null 2>&1
        echo Shot time: $(date +"%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S")
        sleep 30
done
```

i want to create a time-lape video on a specific program (game) :3

maybe use **import -window id** insted of **scrot**? but i still dont understand how it works...

Comment: How do you want to pick the window, manually by clicking on it or by name?

Comment: either are valid i think. i just want to set a window so screenshot program stays on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure if this would work in every DE, but in mine seems to work.

What I did was to run the following line in a terminal:

```
import -window $(xdotool getwindowfocus) -pause 5 asd.png & for i in {1..6}; do echo $i; sleep 1; done
```

Then switched to another window and waited for 10 seconds and I could see the image:
[image]

Of course, you can first get the window ID by running `xdotool` in your desired window then adapt the bash command accordingly.

Comment: yea but ur scipt only can screenshot terminal. for me its more like:
for i in {1..6}; do echo $i; sleep 1; done ; import -window $(xdotool getwindowfocus) asdf.png
first wait then read window id and take sceenshot. anyways xdotool is all i needed. i've eddited my scripts to my needs and it works. tnx